# Loading images from a directory into a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I'm having trouble adding photos from a folder. Using the tensorflow documentation when downloading the training set, we get ndarray.shape in the form (60000, 28, 28). When taking photos from folders, I can't figure out how to make it that way. I would also like to mention that these photos vary in size. I would like to achieve the same shape for my ndarray as with fashion mnist (x, y, z).

```
def loadFiles(path):
  trainImages = []
  for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
       img = cv2.imread(r + "\\" + file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
       trainImages.append(img)

 trainImagesNumpy = np.ndarray(trainImages)
 return trainImagesNumpy

train = loadFiles(trainPath)
```

I using Tensorflow 2.1.0 and python 3.x

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say your images have different sizes, resize them as you read them from the directory, and then append them to `trainImages`.

I'm suggesting two options:

**Option 1:
Modify** `loadFiles` **as follows**

```
def loadFiles(path):
  trainImages = []
  for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
       filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
       img = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

       # Resizing image to size (28, 28)
       img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

       trainImages.append(img)

 trainImagesNumpy = np.ndarray(trainImages)
 return trainImagesNumpy

train = loadFiles(trainPath)
```

You can use other interpolation strategies for resizing. Check out OpenCV Python documentation.

Also, using `os.path.join` is good practice to join base directory path and file path, as it is OS independent. It automatically takes care of the filepath separators in Windows (backslash) or Unix/Linux (forward slash).

Refer: [cv2.resize](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-resizing-using-opencv-python/)

**Option 2: Use the** `ImageDataGenerator` **class in keras**
There are two advantages to using this:

- It loads data in batches.
- You can perform data augmentation very easily using inbuilt parameters.

Organize your data into train, validation and test directories. Each of the directories must contain subdirectories for each of the n classes.

The directory tree will look as follows (say you are doing a binary classification of cats vs dogs):

```
.
├── test
│   ├── cats
│   └── dogs
├── train
│   ├── cats
│   └── dogs
└── validation
    ├── cats
    └── dogs
```

Then initialize a data generator, rescale the images from 0-255 to 0-1 range if you desire.

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

Then read the training, validation and test images as batches from the `flow_from_directory` method.

```
train = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train', target_size=(28, 28), batch_size=32)
validation = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/validation', target_size=(28, 28), batch_size=32)
test = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test', target_size=(28, 28), batch_size=32)
```

Once you've executed the above code, make sure it tells you it's found the correct number of images with the correct number of classes.

You can then pass `train`, `validation` and `test` batches directly to the `fit` method in your keras model. **Make sure you specify the number of** `steps_per_epoch` **and** `validation_steps` **while training.** This is because generators run forever, continuously generating images, so `fit` needs to know when to stop. Make sure you provide the `steps` argument to the `predict` method as well, for the same reason.

Refer:
[Keras docs](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: Just a caution - cv2 reads in images as BGR as opposed to RGB. You can convert them to RGB with img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).

Comment: @GerryP Good point to keep in mind. However, it seems the OP is using grayscale images (mentions same shape as images in Fashion MNIST).